# Blurry Video on TV when going through Desktop GPU

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, display, tv

Ok so I have a Samsung 46 in led with a Native resolution of 1920x1080
this one for reference:
http://www.samsung.com/us/video/tvs/UN46EH6000FXZA

I also have it connected to my Desktop (with a 570gtx GPU).

When I play videos through the PS3 (as a media center) the video quality is fine, however when I switch Monitor inputs to the TV(just playing through the desktop--->tv as a monitor)...the videos always look blurry?

Why is this?

and is there any solutions to fix it?

Comment: How exactly are you connecting the TV to the PC?  On the PC< what resolution are you trying to use for the TV?

Comment: Also look for how to set your tv to 1:1 pixel mapping/disable overscan/whatever samsung call it.

Comment: TV to PC is through an brand new HDMI mini cable. the tv resolution im using is 1920x1080 (which is native for the tv)

Comment: Is it just videos that are blurry, or everything that gets sent from the computer to the TV (including UI elements)?

Comment: Seems like most things are blurry TBH, but it's especially noticeable in videos